# conditional rendering does not work with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my state and I want to display the component if the value is true but in the console I receive the error message
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state
my code

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

const Index = () => {

  const [test, setTest]= useState(true);
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  function RenderToast() {

    return (
      <div>
        { addToast('message') }
      </div>
    )}

    return (
      <div>
        {test &&  <RenderToast /> }
      </div>
    )

  

}
```

Comment: You've got to return statements. Only the first one will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You're combining the return of the `RenderToast` component with the return from `Index`. Separate them so you return some JSX from `RenderToast` and then return JSX from `Index` based on the value of the state.

```
function Index() {

  const [test, setTest] = useState(true);
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  function RenderToast() {
    return (
      <div>
        { addToast('message') }
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {test &&  <RenderToast /> }
    </div>
   );

}
```

Comment: i do this but its not working i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what useToasts() does, but I think you are trying to change state during the render phase.

Try this:

```
function Index() {

      const [test, setTest] = useState(true);
      const { addToast } = useToasts();

      function RenderToast() {
        const [toast, setToast] = useState(null)

        useEffect(() => {
            setToast(addToast('message'));
        });

        return (
          <div>
            { toast }
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div>
          {test &&  <RenderToast /> }
        </div>
       );

    }
```

Comment: I try But i got this Error: The `useToasts` hook must be called from a descendent of the `ToastProvider`.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Then you can wrap ```<RenderToast />``` (or any of its ancestors) with ```ToastProvider```